# DB deadlock when trying to delete same row in 2 different transactions

Tags: mysql, deadlock, database-deadlocks

I have 3 tables:

tableA with columns: id(varchar, PK), name(varchar)

tableB with columns: id(varchar, PK), name(varchar)

tableAB is a junction table with columns: A_id and B_id (PK is a_id,b_id) and I have an index on B_id and NO index on A_id.

Database is mysql and is running with READ_COMITTED, hence no gap locks.
Engine is InnoDB

I have 2 transactions running concurrently each transaction is executing the following operations:

```
START TRANSACTION
Delete from tableAB where A_id in (someID);
Delete from tableA where id in (someID)
END TRANSACTION
```

What I am seeing is that sometimes I get a deadlock exception, I am unable to reproduce it locally but in production it happens like once a week.

```
------------------------
LATEST DETECTED DEADLOCK
------------------------
2018-03-12 17:38:21 2b081ba80700
*** (1) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 5929005987, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 1 row lock(s)
MySQL thread id 2190, OS thread handle 0x2b0841544700, query id 12965152738 172.19.129.231 apptio updating
DELETE FROM `tableAB` WHERE A_id IN (''ddf8ecf3-8824-4f37-9b27-2968d2ba647c'')
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 58 page no 16 n bits 145 index `PRIMARY` of table `tableAB` trx id 5929005987 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap waiting
Record lock, heap no 145 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len=30; bufptr=0x2b02eac266a7; hex= 64646638656366332d383832342d346633372d396232372d323936386432; asc ddf8ecf3-8824-4f37-9b27-2968d2; (total 36 bytes);
 1: len=5; bufptr=0x2b02eac266cb; hex= 41646d696e; asc Admin;;
 2: len=6; bufptr=0x2b02eac266d0; hex= 00016165739c; asc   aes ;;
 3: len=7; bufptr=0x2b02eac266d6; hex= 4b000004ee251f; asc K    % ;;

*** (2) TRANSACTION:
TRANSACTION 5929005980, ACTIVE 0 sec updating or deleting
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1
LOCK WAIT 7 lock struct(s), heap size 376, 10 row lock(s), undo log entries 8
MySQL thread id 2191, OS thread handle 0x2b080bbc7700, query id 12965152752 172.19.129.231 apptio updating
DELETE FROM `tableA` WHERE id IN (''ddf8ecf3-8824-4f37-9b27-2968d2ba647c'')
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S):
RECORD LOCKS space id 58 page no 16 n bits 145 index `PRIMARY` of table `tableAB` trx id 5929005980 lock_mode X locks rec but not gap
Record lock, heap no 145 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len=30; bufptr=0x2b02eac266a7; hex= 64646638656366332d383832342d346633372d396232372d323936386432; asc ddf8ecf3-8824-4f37-9b27-2968d2; (total 36 bytes);
 1: len=5; bufptr=0x2b02eac266cb; hex= 41646d696e; asc Admin;;
 2: len=6; bufptr=0x2b02eac266d0; hex= 00016165739c; asc   aes ;;
 3: len=7; bufptr=0x2b02eac266d6; hex= 4b000004ee251f; asc K    % ;;

[bitmap of 256 bytes in hex: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 00 00 00 f0 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ]
*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED:
RECORD LOCKS space id 58 page no 16 n bits 145 index `PRIMARY` of table `tableAB` trx id 5929005980 lock mode S waiting
Record lock, heap no 145 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 32
 0: len=30; bufptr=0x2b02eac266a7; hex= 64646638656366332d383832342d346633372d396232372d323936386432; asc ddf8ecf3-8824-4f37-9b27-2968d2; (total 36 bytes);
 1: len=5; bufptr=0x2b02eac266cb; hex= 41646d696e; asc Admin;;
 2: len=6; bufptr=0x2b02eac266d0; hex= 00016165739c; asc   aes ;;
 3: len=7; bufptr=0x2b02eac266d6; hex= 4b000004ee251f; asc K    % ;;
```

Comment: What DB engine is on each table?

Comment: @LoganBertram its InnoDB

Comment: A deadlock isn't something that's *really* bad. It's just MySQL's way of dealing with concurrency. You said you get it once a week - that's basically nothing. You even identified why it happens. The obvious solution is "don't delete the same row twice" but that's not something you can control :)

Comment: @N.B. well I have not identified why it happens, basically I delete from junction(tableAB) table and then table A in a single txn. If 2 txns do the same operation then both should try to get a lock first on tableAB record and then on tableA record. Only one txn should get a row lock on tableAB and other txn should wait, so I am not really sure why and how they deadlock.